# How to implement 3D touch to a tableview cell to preview that cell with Swift 4?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoapods, swift4, 3dtouch

I've got a tableview within a normal viewcontroller and I was wondering if there was a way to implement 3D touch to preview a row either using Swift 4 or with a CocoaPod?

I've tried looking for a CocoaPod, but the one I want to use (on cocoapods.org) uses Objective C to implement it, not Swift 4 and I'm not sure how to convert it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without frameworks pretty straightforward too.

As one of solutions: create **custom UIView class** as background of whole cell, in created UIView class you have 3 methods:

`touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)`,

`touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)`,

`touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)`

You can detect touches in those methods, all you have to do is just get `touch.force`, compare it to `maximumPossibleForce`, and your 3D-Touch will be detected. In `touchesBegan` implement preview as subview over current view.

In `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled` you simply reset cell to the original state. (remove your subview with preview from superview)

This is not the really right way to do this. Try better method (but its harder too), described in this good article: https://medium.com/@ashok.nfn/getting-started-with-3d-touch-peek-pop-swift-d498da57ae19 (you need second one - Peek and Pop)